How to transpile #private to _public?
For backwards compatibility purposes I want to transpile my JavaScript private properties to public properties, both fields and methods.  Babel does it, but the accurate way, as WeakMap. I see no advantage to that in my current case. It bloats the code I'm about to minify, and a standard public property performs better. If I set the privateFieldsAsProperties compiler assumption, it still bloats/mangles the code with _classPrivateFieldLooseBase and _classPrivateFieldLooseKey.
I want to execute a straight find-and-replace of # to _. I have verified that there are no conflicting names, and that my regular expression captures all the relevant cases (it excludes cases where preceded by ampersand or single, back, or double quote).  I'll run Babel's class-properties plugin to remove/relocate the field declarations that are left behind.
Or is there another transpiler that does this, or a Babel option I'm missing?  Closure Compiler doesn't do private properties.
The context is GitHub Actions. There is a built-in Find and Replace Action, but its regular expressions syntax doesn't support my regex: (?<!['`"&])[#]. So I'm thinking that I'll have go it alone with sed as a shell action, and run it before Babel (or send the output to Babel). Is that plausible? Is anyone already doing this?

sed also would not support that regexp syntax. Neither would awk if you're considering that next. You'd need a tool that supports PCREs, e.g. perl, python, or ruby.

I'd suggest not using a regex at all but write a plugin using an AST parser that transforms the code only where needed. Easier than trying to regex it.

@EdMorton - So no lookbacks in sed or awk? It has been decades since I have used them. Thanks for the info.

@SidewaysS correct, there's just no need for them since it's easy to do what you'd want them for using existing constructs (in awk at least) and so by not supporting look-whatevers the regexp engine can be faster and the language less cluttered.

@VLAZ - yes, the more I get into my build process, the more I think I'm going to need some kind of script. I've used perl, but a while ago. I don't know much about AST, but from the little I read while investigating this yesterday, it does seem to be the rightly-guided approach.  Seemed like overkill for this one task, but I might have another task or two that has more involved parsing. Thanks for the suggestion.

@SidewaysS see AST Explorer for what the AST of some code will look like. Here is an example. If you click somewhere in the code on the left, you'd see the node on the right. So, if you click in #myField it'd say it's type: "PrivateIdentifier" and name: "myField".  You can also change the parser at the top (it's currently set to acorn) as different ones may present the AST slightly differently.

@VLAZ - After poking around docs and discussions, I think that a Babel plugin is the best solution. It will be a simpler version of @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods. It precludes the need for any standalone scripts, since I'm already using Babel. The AST is built-in and wrapped-up, which should make it easier. I searched npmjs.com for "babel plugin private" and no one seems to have done it for me :( I'm working my way through the babel handbook now...
